# Git does not apply remote.pushDefault and branch.<name>.pushRemote configuration

Tags: git, version-control

My understanding is that when deciding what remote to push to, Git uses (in order of priority) 1) the remote and refspec provided as arguments to the command, 2)The `branch.<name>.pushRemote` configuration for the branch your pushing from, 3)the `remote.pushDefault` configuration which applies to all branches (and is the configuration I would prefer to use in this case, and 4)the `branch.<name>.remote` configuration which Git sets up for you automatically when you clone a repository.

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

I've cloned my repository from a central repository ("origin") that I don't have write access to, used git remote add to point to my own public repository that I do have write access to ("submit"). I tried to set remote.pushDefault and branch.develop.pushRemote to my "submit" repository, but whenever I type git push, it tries to push to the central repository "origin".

Using git version 1.7.1, on Centos 6.7

Here's my config file:

[image: My config file]

Here's the evidence:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem because CentOS is so far behind modern versions of git.  The quoted text below is from the release notes (`Documentation/RelNotes/*` files).

1. `branch.branch.pushRemote` and `remote.pushDefault` were both new in git 1.8.3:

   > - A triangular "pull from one place, push to another place" workflow
   >     is supported better by new `remote.pushdefault` (overrides the
   >     "origin" thing) and `branch.*.pushremote` (overrides the
   >     `branch.*.remote`) configuration variables.
2. The handling for the new features was still somewhat broken until git 1.9.1:

   > - "git push" did not pay attention to `branch.*.pushremote` if it is
   >     defined earlier than `remote.pushdefault`; the order of these two
   >     variables in the configuration file should not matter, but it did
   >     by mistake.

Obviously item 1 is much more important than item 2, since the release notes provide the workaround (and in fact your config already has them in the necessary order, and of course both are set to the same value anyway).

You'll need to upgrade git, to at least 1.8.3 (though there's no reason not to jump to 2.5+, as long as you make note of the interface changes in 2.0).

Comment: Thanks! How would I go about finding this if you hadn't told me about it? You've referred me to Documentation/RelNotes/*, is that at https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/Documentation/RelNotes? I see over a hundred files there, how would I find which one contains info about a specific feature like remote.pushDefault?

Comment: Yes - your best bet is to clone the git source (your relatively ancient git should still have no problem doing that) and then build git from source.  What I do with the RelNotes files is grep (or sometimes git grep) through them.  (And, I'm terrible about voting on questions and answers myself...)